# how to set date as primarykey in entity with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity with 3 primary key That third is type of date and when i try to insert data in entity i encounter an error -->
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.util.Date

i found the solution for String but not for date type.

and this is my entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class PartyContactMech extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long partyId;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long contactMechPurposeId;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Date fromDate;

@Column
private Date usedSince;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ContactMech> ContactMeches;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ContactMechPurpose contactMechPurpose;

public Long getPartyId() {
    return partyId;
}

public void setPartyId(Long partyId) {
    this.partyId = partyId;
}

public Long getContactMechPurposeId() {
    return contactMechPurposeId;
}

public void setContactMechPurposeId(Long contactMechPurposeId) {
    this.contactMechPurposeId = contactMechPurposeId;
}

public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}

public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}

public Date getUsedSince() {
    return usedSince;
}

public void setUsedSince(Date usedSince) {
    this.usedSince = usedSince;
}

public List<ContactMech> getContactMeches() {
    return ContactMeches;
}

public void setContactMeches(List<ContactMech> contactMeches) {
    ContactMeches = contactMeches;
}

public ContactMechPurpose getContactMechPurpose() {
    return contactMechPurpose;
}

public void setContactMechPurpose(ContactMechPurpose contactMechPurpose)                              
{
    this.contactMechPurpose = contactMechPurpose;
    }
}
```

anyone can help,thanks

Comment: multiple @Id is wrong. Read about composite key, or better rethink Your project to classic single integer primary key

Comment: thanks for reply if you check moqui framework there is entity with name PartyContactMech that have 3 primary key

Comment: I had googled somewhere (in Apache Of Biz network) single primary key `partyId`. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjUp6yeoOzaAhWpiqYKHY6yCKcQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcwiki.apache.org%2Fconfluence%2Fdownload%2Fattachments%2F13271792%2FOFBizDatamodelBook_11x17_1of4_20081029.pdf%3Fapi%3Dv2&usg=AOvVaw0MnA4hUMStGnDQyEAD2Gsb

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` fromDate. `GenerationType.AUTO` is for autoIncrement field.

Comment: but i have another error -->Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into PartyContactMech (thru_date, contactMechPurpose_id, usedSince, partyId, fromDate, contactMechPurposeId, id) values (NULL, 34, NULL, 31, '2018-5-4 18:21:36.666000 +4:30:0', 32, 33) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.

Comment: `<philosophic>`there is a correct answer, but not to Your question `</philosophic>`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
@Column
private long id;
```